# Является ли "наконец-то" вводным словом в предложении и требует ли обособления?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Нужно ли обособить "наконец-то" в следующем предложении?

> *Ну, наконец-то, ты проснулась, а то я уже устала ждать!*

Мне кажется, это вводное слово, а следовательно, требует обособления с обеих сторон.

Answer (score 3):

**Наконец-то ты проснулась!** Разве нужна запятая? Ни в коем случае.

Так и в вашем случае.

Answer (score 1):

Niemand совершенно прав.

***Наконец (наконец-то)*** может быть вводным словом и наречием (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_436)). В данном случае это наречие со значением *"в конечном итоге, напоследок".* Поэтому обособлять его неправильно в вашем случае.

*"Ну"* в данном случае *частица,* а не междометие (паузы нет, всё произносится одним махом), поэтому после неё запятая тоже не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Во фразеологическом словаре:
[наконец](https://phrasebook_ru.academic.ru/859/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86)
**Наконец-то!** — восклицание для выражения радости, удовольствия вследствие появления или осуществления чего-нибудь долго ожидаемого.
*Наконец-то я увидел тебя!*
 *Наконец-то Путин проснулся!* (Я. Кедми)

Нужной/спорной может может быть только запятая после "ну".

Ну наконец-то ты проснулся (О. Лунев).
Ну, наконец-то ты проснулась (С. Жучкова).
Ну наконец-то ты проснулась, соня (А. Бартон).
Ну, наконец-то ты проснулся (А. Гавриленко).

[Наконец-то](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86-%D1%82%D0%BE)

Comment: Очень мало могу себе представить людей, делающих паузу после "ну" во фразе Нары.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, огромное спасибо за объяснение